# What does the suffix e+number mean in python at the end of a float?

Tags: python

I use `random.uniform(1,2**100)` to produce random floats to the range `(0,2**100)`. Some results are :

```
>>> random.uniform(1,2**100)
5.9798650563331964e+29
>>> random.uniform(1,2**100)
8.439133849811236e+29
>>> random.uniform(1,2**100)
1.1367823572756921e+30
>>> random.uniform(1,2**100)
6.467828850316163e+29
>>> random.uniform(1,2**100)
6.114089228136624e+29
>>> random.uniform(1,2**100)
5.8262139039159224e+29
```

I can't get the interpretation of `e+29` at the end of each number.

Comment: It is a **very** large number. `1.23e+45` means `1.23 * 10**45` or `123xxx` where `xxx` is 43 zeros.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's know as [E notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), which is plain text representation of [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

`1.234e+56` means `1.234 * 10**56` or in more human readable form 1.234 × 10<sup>56</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

"e+number" means 10 to the power of a positive number, in case of a negative number it would be like "e-number".

Comment: If you want to be helpful you should provide examples and a bit more explanation, as the asker is obviously unfamiliar with mathematical notations.